# dnsmasq server with os x clients

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, internal-dns

I've set up dnsmasq on an ubuntu server on a small local network with several clients including some Windows and some OS X.  Windows clients are working great.  The OS X clients are having the classic "dig works but ping doesn't" problem.  I've done some research but I can't find information about the way OS X's DNS resolution DOES work.  I can only find documentation that tells me it doesn't use the same facility as dig.

My question is: Why can my Windows clients and dig on OS X properly resolve local names configured by dnsmasq but the OS X system can't?  I've suspected that it has something to do with the fact that dnsmasq doesn't provide SOA records, but I'm not sure.  I've also experimented with bind9 instead, but I can't seem to get the configuration right on it.

Here are the contents of my dnsmasq config file:

```
no-dhcp-interface=en0
address=/neptune.local/neptune/192.168.42.2
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 2):

If `dig` works without having to specify a particular nameserver, then both your server and Mac OS client are probably configured correctly.  It's likely that your Mac has cached a negative DNS result.  (`dig` runs the DNS query bypassing the cache; `ping` uses the system name resolver, which uses the cache.) To clear the cache, run `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` (Mac OS ≤ 10.6) or `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` (Mac OS ≥ 10.7).